# Tensor notation?

Tags: tensors

I'm reading about Tensors at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_(machine_learning)).  The following notation is used to describe tensor ${\mathcal A}$, can anyone explain what it means?  To me it looks like the cartesian product of multiple domains, however I'm confused because it seems to be raising the base to a power.  I'm guessing the superscript is used to describe this object differently because I can't see how the base could be raised to the result of the cartesian product.  Thanks

${\mathcal A}$ is an $I_0 \times I_1 \times \cdots I_C$ array over $\mathbb F$

${\mathcal A} \in {\mathbb F}^{I_0 \times I_1 \times \ldots \times I_C}$

One basic approach (not the only way) to using tensors in machine learning is to embed various data types directly. For example, a grayscale image, commonly represented as a discrete 2D function $f(x,y)$ with resolution $N \times M<$ may be embedded in a mode-2 tensor as
: $f(x,y) \mapsto \mathcal{A}\in \mathbb{R}^{N \times M}.$

Comment: Looking on the linked Wikipedia page, it says that the $I_i$ are just positive integers, so $\mathbb{F}^{I_1\times\dots\times I_C}$ is just $\mathbb F^n$ for some integer $n$, that is, the set (vector space) of all $n$-tuples with entries in $\mathbb{F}$.

Comment: If they were sets, it would still make sense, though—the notation $\mathbb F^S$ (where $S$ is a set) is often used to denote the vector space over $\mathbb F$ with basis $S$. When $S$ is finite this is essentially the same as $\mathbb F^{|S|}$ where $|S|$ is the cardinality of $S$.

Comment: So it's basically the cartesian product over some domain or field.  An array in computer science?

Comment: Yeah—although there is a bit of a subtlety if the set $S$ is infinite, but when $S$ is finite/$n$ is finite then $\mathbb F^S$ or $\mathbb F^n$ is (as a set) just the Cartesian product of $\mathbb F$ with itself $|S|$ or $n$ times, respectively.